# Deserialize xml by linq, default with many elements

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml, deserialization

I have this xml that i want to deserialize, but the problem is that I cannot get all the `<food>` elements in each day. Is there any way to deserialize it by linq

```
<foodplaces>
    <foodplace>
        <name> The Indian Restaurant</name>
        <week> 47 </week>
        <monday>
            <food> Pasta </food>
            <food> chineese food</food>
            <food> veg food </food>
        </monday>
        -<tuesday>
            <food> Indian food</food>
            <food> Veg food </food>
        </tuesday>
    </foodplace>

    <name> Restauran Italian </name>
    <week> 47 </week>
    -<monday>
        <food> Pizza </food>
        <food> Checken      </food>
        <food>  sallad </food>
    </monday>
    -<tuesday>
        <food> Fish </food>
        <food>  ris </food>
        <food> Biff </food>
        <food> Checken </food>
    </tuesday>
</foodplaces>
```

and have these classes

```
public   class tuesday
{
    private string[] _foods = new string[3];
    public string food1
    {
        set { _foods[0] = value; }
    }
    public string food2
    {
        set { _foods[1] = value; }
    }
    public string food3
    {
        set { _foods[2] = value; }
    }
}

public class foodplace
{
    private string _name;
    private string _week;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public string week
    {
        get { return _week; }
        set { _week = value; }
    }
    public monday m = new monday();
    public tuesday t = new tuesday();
}
```

And have this code to deserialize data from `XmlDocument` to the class, but it does not seem to work

```
foodplace fd = new foodplace();

List<foodplace> foodplaces =
    (from _foodplace in xdocument.Element("foodplaces").Elements("foodplace")
     select new foodplace
     {
         name = _foodplace.Element("name").Value,
         week = _foodplace.Element("week").Value,          
         m = (from _day in _foodplace.Elements("monday")
              select new tuesday 
              {                   
                  food1 = _day.Element("food").Value,
                  food2 = _day.Element("food").Value,                  
                  food3 = _day.Element("food").Value                      
              })
```

Comment: Why you deserialize in this manner? What about `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: cus the xml is on URl link, and i want to check and varify each element against any injection before assigning it ti the class.

Comment: Verify them in your setter.

Comment: Your xml seems to be missing a second foodplace begin and end element, is that expected?  Also why are you creating a `tuesday` object from the monday element, maybe the class should be 'DayOfWeek`?  Please include any relevant information about why this isn't working (errors, expected vs actual results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few bugs here:

1. The XML for "Restauran Italian" is not bracketed by a  `<foodplace>  </foodplace>`.  It should be.
2. You select elements named "monday", store their data in a `tuesday` class, them set them in the `m` field, which is a `monday`.  Surely those should all be "monday".  Have you even fixed your compiler errors?
3. There are three `food` elements, so you must enumerate through them, similarly to what you are doing with the `foodplace` elements.  `_day.Element("food").Value` (repeatedly) gets the first.

Thus the following is a fix:

```
        string xml = @"
        <foodplaces>
            <foodplace>
                <name> The Indian Restaurant</name>
                <week> 47 </week>
                <monday>
                    <food> Pasta </food>
                    <food> chineese food</food>
                    <food> veg food </food>
                </monday>
                <tuesday>
                    <food> Indian food</food>
                    <food> Veg food </food>
                </tuesday>
            </foodplace>
            <foodplace>
                <name> Restauran Italian </name>
                <week> 47 </week>
                <monday>
                    <food> Pizza </food>
                    <food> Checken      </food>
                    <food>  sallad </food>
                </monday>
                <tuesday>
                    <food> Fish </food>
                    <food>  ris </food>
                    <food> Biff </food>
                    <food> Checken </food>
                </tuesday>
            </foodplace>
        </foodplaces>
        ";
```

And

```
        List<foodplace> foodplaces =
            (from _foodplace in xdocument.Element("foodplaces").Elements("foodplace")
             select new foodplace
             {
                 name = _foodplace.Element("name").Value,
                 week = _foodplace.Element("week").Value,
                 m = (from _day in _foodplace.Elements("monday")
                      let list = _day.Elements("food").Take(3).ToList()
                      select new monday
                      {
                          food1 = (list.Count > 0 ? list[0].Value : string.Empty),
                          food2 = (list.Count > 1 ? list[1].Value : string.Empty),
                          food3 = (list.Count > 2 ? list[2].Value : string.Empty),
                      }).FirstOrDefault(),
             }).ToList();
```

This works.

As an aside, having separate classes for `monday`, `tuesday`, etc etc seems wrong.  Make a base class `RestaurantDay` and subclass as required.  Also, I'd suggest reviewing the [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for c#, your code could be more readable, for instance the public field `m` should become a public property like so:

```
 public Monday Monday { get; set; }
```

Comment: i just wanted the right linq syntax to deserialize all elements.
Thanks, this solved my problem